# Multiple Tables in a Table: Merging Rows

Tags: tables, merge, rows

[image: Table to be created]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \captionof{table}{abc}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 1$, $b = 1$}} \\
        \hline          
            Cl1 & Cl2 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
             & aa & bb & cc & dd & ee \\            
            \hline
            1 & 4 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14  \\
            \hline 
            2 &  & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
            \hline
            3 &  & 7 & 10 & 13 & 16 \\
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}
\bigskip
            \captionof{table}{def}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 2$, $b = 2$}} \\
    \hline          
    Cl1 & Cl2 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
    & aa & bb & cc & dd & ee \\         
    \hline
    1 & 6 & 7 & 12 & 17 & 22  \\
    \hline 
    2 &  & 8 & 13 & 18 & 23 \\
    \hline
    3 &  & 9 & 14 & 19 & 24 \\
    \hline          
    4 &  & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 \\
    \hline
    5 &  & 11 & 16 & 21 & 26 \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \captionof{table}{ghi}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 3$, $b = 3$}} \\
    \hline          
    Cl1 & Cl2 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
    & aa & bb & cc & dd & ee \\         
    \hline
    1 & 10 & 11 & 20 & 29 & 38  \\
    \hline 
    2 &  & 12 & 21 & 30 & 39 \\
    \hline
    3 &  & 13 & 22 & 31 & 40 \\
    \hline          
    4 &  & 14 & 23 & 32 & 41 \\
    \hline
    5 &  & 15 & 24 & 33 & 42 \\
    \hline  
    6 &  & 16 & 25 & 34 & 43 \\
    \hline
    7 &  & 17 & 26 & 35 & 44 \\
    \hline          
    8 &  & 18 & 27 & 36 & 45 \\
    \hline
    9 &  & 19 & 28 & 37 & 46 \\
    \hline      
    \end{tabular}

    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: I am able to obtain this]

Appreciate help in fine tuning the remaining portion!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

With use of `multirow` package and `\cline{...}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \captionof{table}{abc}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 1$, $b = 1$}} \\
        \hline
            Cl1 & Cl2 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
             & aa & bb & cc & dd & ee \\
        \hline
            1 & \multirow{3}{*}{4}
                 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14  \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
            2 &  & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
            3 &  & 7 & 10 & 13 & 16 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\bigskip
            \captionof{table}{def}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 2$, $b = 2$}} \\
    \hline
    Cl1 & Cl2 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
    & aa & bb & cc & dd & ee \\
    \hline
    1 & \multirow{5}{*}{6}
         & 7 & 12 & 17 & 22  \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    2 &  & 8 & 13 & 18 & 23 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    3 &  & 9 & 14 & 19 & 24 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    4 &  & 10 & 15 & 20 & 25 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    5 &  & 11 & 16 & 21 & 26 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \captionof{table}{ghi}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 3$, $b = 3$}} \\
    \hline
    Cl1 & Cl2 & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
    & aa & bb & cc & dd & ee \\
    \hline
    1 & \multirow{9}{*}{10}
         & 11 & 20 & 29 & 38  \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    2 &  & 12 & 21 & 30 & 39 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    3 &  & 13 & 22 & 31 & 40 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    4 &  & 14 & 23 & 32 & 41 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    5 &  & 15 & 24 & 33 & 42 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    6 &  & 16 & 25 & 34 & 43 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    7 &  & 17 & 26 & 35 & 44 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    8 &  & 18 & 27 & 36 & 45 \\
        \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
    9 &  & 19 & 28 & 37 & 46 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

With use of `tanularray` package the tables code become much shorter ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \captionof{table}{abc}
        \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,4-Z}=solid, vlines,
                     colspec={*{6}{c}},
                     }
    \SetCell[c=6]{c}    $a = 1$, $b = 1$        \\
    Cl1 & Cl2   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Cl3, Cl4
                        &       & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Cl5, Cl6
                                        &       \\
        & aa    &   bb  &   cc  &   dd  &   ee  \\
    1   & \SetCell[r=3]{c}    4
                &       &       &       \\
    2   &       &   5   &   8   &   11  &  14   \\
    3   &       &   7   &   10  &  13   &   16  \\
    \end{tblr}
\bigskip
            \captionof{table}{def}
        \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,4-Z}=solid, vlines,
                     colspec={*{6}{c}},
                     }
    \SetCell[c=6]{c}    $a = 2$, $b = 2$        \\
    Cl1 & Cl2   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Cl3, Cl4
                        &       & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Cl5, Cl6
                                        &       \\
        & aa    &   bb  &   cc  &   dd  &   ee  \\
    1   & \SetCell[r=5]{c} 6
                &   7   &   12  &   17  &   22  \\
    2   &       &   8   &   13  &   18  &   23  \\
    3   &       &   9   &   14  &   19  &   24  \\
    4   &       &   10  &   15  &   20  &   25  \\
    5   &       &   11  &   16  &   21  &   26  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{minipage}
%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
            \captionof{table}{ghi}
        \begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,4-Z}=solid, vlines,
                     colspec={*{6}{c}},
                     }
    \SetCell[c=6]{c}    $a = 3$, $b = 3$        \\
    Cl1 & Cl2   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Cl3, Cl4
                        &       & \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Cl5, Cl6
                                        &       \\
        & aa    &   bb  &   cc  &   dd  &   ee  \\
    1   & \SetCell[r=9]{c} 10
                &   11  &   20  &   29  &   38  \\
    2   &       &   12  &   21  &   30  &   39  \\
    3   &       &   13  &   22  &   31  &   40  \\
    4   &       &   14  &   23  &   32  &   41  \\
    5   &       &   15  &   24  &   33  &   42  \\
    6   &       &   16  &   25  &   34  &   43  \\
    7   &       &   17  &   26  &   35  &   44  \\
    8   &       &   18  &   27  &   36  &   45  \\
    9   &       &   19  &   28  &   37  &   46  \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @ltxEnthu, you are welcome. Now I add also solution with `tabularray`

Comment: When data is entered in the table, all tables expand in horizontal directions and there is overlap. How to avoid the overlap?

Comment: @ltxEnthu, which data? Data, which you provide are in tables. If those data is some dummy numbers, than please at least mimic real width of data. Apparently thex are wider as you have space for table (`0.5\textwidt`)

Comment: The ones used for illustration has dummy numbers. With real data (decimal numbers) the overlap begins.

Comment: @ltxEnthu, do you read my comment carefully?  I (or anyone) can't help you, if you will not provide at least one row in the first and last table with real cells contents. ISO please, edit your question and do what I ask you. It is not so hard ...

Answer (score 2):

`\valign` primitive can be used here too:

```
\def\vcell#1{\hbox to2.5em{\lower.5em\vbox to2em{}\hss#1\unskip\hss}}
\def\bcell#1{\hrule \vss\vcell{#1}\vss}
\def\p #1/#2 {\vbox{\medskip\halign{\hfil##\hfil\cr #1\cr#2\cr}\smallskip}}
\def\l{\crcr\noalign{\vrule}}
\vbox{
\hbox{\valign{&\hrule\vcell{#}\cr\l
  \p Cl1/   & 1 & 2 & 3 \cr\l
  \p Cl2/aa & \multispan3  \bcell{4} \cr\l
  \p Cl2/bb & 5 & 6 & 7 \cr\l
  \p Cl4/cc & 8 & 9 & 10 \cr\l
  \p Cl5/dd & 11 & 12 & 13 \cr\l
  \p Cl6/ee & 14 & 15 & 16 \cr\l
}}
\hrule
}
```

Note that the data are written here column per column, no row per row.

Answer (score 0):

First table proposition with booktabs (I think that vertical bar should never appear in a table...) another proposition with your tabular presentation :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \captionof{table}{abc}
        \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
            \toprule
                \multicolumn{6}{c}{{$a = 1$, $b = 1$}} \\
            \midrule          
                \makecell[c]{Cl1} & \makecell[c]{Cl2\\aa} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell[c]{Cl3, Cl4\\bb, cc}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell[c]{Cl5, Cl6\\ dd, ee}} \\
            \midrule
            1 & \multirow{3}{*}{4} & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14  \\
            2 &  & 6 & 9 & 12 & 15 \\
            3 &  & 7 & 10 & 13 & 16 \\
            \hline          
        \end{tabular}
        \bigskip
        \captionof{table}{def}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{{$a = 2$, $b = 2$}}                                                                     \\ \hline
            Cl1 &               Cl2                & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl3, Cl4}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{{Cl5, Cl6}} \\
                &                aa                & bb &             cc              & dd &             ee              \\ \hline
             1  & \multirow{5}{*}{6} & 7  &             12              & 17 &             22              \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
             2  &                                  & 8  &             13              & 18 &             23              \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
             3  &                                  & 9  &             14              & 19 &             24              \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
             4  &                                  & 10 &             15              & 20 &             25              \\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-6}
             5  &                                  & 11 &             16              & 21 &             26              \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```